# How to update HTML block in IPython

Tags: python, html, streaming, jupyter-notebook

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989509/automaticaly-update-image-in-ipython-notebook) I posted, but is more specific (and hopefully gets more specific answers).

I am trying to display `png` images on an IPython notebook, and update the display as the png files are updated.

One possible solution is below. Unfortunately, my implementation does not update the file, and creates a new HTML block at the end of the old one. What I want instead, is to replace the old HTML block with the new one -i.e. replace the content only.

As example code, I have two notebooks. One notebook generates `pngs` and saves them in a `figures` directory.

```
import os
import glob
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for ix in range(20):
    N = 50
    x = np.random.rand(N)
    y = np.random.rand(N)
    colors = np.random.rand(N)
    area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2 # 0 to 15 point radiuses

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
    fig.savefig(os.path.join("figures", "fig1.png"), bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.close(fig)
    time.sleep(3)
```

A second notebook shows the `png`s It is supposed top show a single png which updates. Instead it stacks the same `png` on itself, every time the `png` is updated.

```
import os
import time
from IPython.html.widgets import interact, interactive, fixed
from IPython.html import widgets
from IPython.display import clear_output, display, HTML

def get_latest_file_ts(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png", strip_directory=True):
    """
    Continuously check for modifications to the file file_name in directory. If file has been
    modified after touched_on, return the Unix timestamp of the modification time.
    :param directory: string / the directory where the file is
    :param file_name: string / the file name
    :param strip_directory: boolean /  if True, strip the directory part of the file name
    :return:
    """
    if strip_directory:
        fname = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    else:
        fname = file_name
    try:
        return os.stat(fname).st_mtime
    except:
        print "FileNotFoundException: Could not find file %s" % fname
        return None


def check_if_modified_file(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png",
                       touched_on=1420070400, sleep_time=1, strip_directory=True):
    """
    Continuously check for modifications to the file file_name in directory. If file has been
    modified after touched_on, return the Unix timestamp of the modification time.
    :param directory: string / the directory where the file is
    :param file_name: string / the file name
    :param touched_on: float / the Unix timestamp on which the file was last modified
    :param sleep_time: float / wait time between interactions
    :param strip_directory: boolean /  if True, strip the directory part of the file name
    :return:
    """
    if strip_directory:
        fname = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    else:
        fname = file_name
    while True:
        try:
            latest_touch = os.stat(fname).st_mtime
            if latest_touch == touched_on:
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
            else:
                return latest_touch
        except:
            print "FileNotFoundException: Could not find %s" % fname
            return None

def show_figs(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png"):
    s = """<figure>\n\t<img src="%s" alt="The figure" width="304" height="228">\n</figure>""" % os.path.join(directory, file_name)
    display(HTML(s))


timestamp = get_latest_file_ts(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png", strip_directory=True)
show_figs(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png")
cnt = 1
while True and cnt < 4:
    timestamp = check_if_modified_file(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png", touched_on=timestamp, sleep_time=1, strip_directory=True)
    display(HTML(""))
    show_figs(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png")
    time.sleep(1)
    cnt += 1
```

(as you can see I have added upper limits on the executions of both the generator and consumer loops)

Any help on how to make widgets update HTML content would be awesome.

Comment: Can you add code that executes?

Comment: @User: I added full working code to the question.

Comment: Actually, you are not using widgets, but just the IPython display machinery to render your images. Nevertheless, you have already imported the ``clear_output`` function. Just give it a try, calling it right before you call ``show_figs``. On my machine it works fine.

Comment: @Jakob. Thanks! I'm removing `widgets` from the title and the tags. You are right about `clear_output` part, now the images are not stacked on top of each other. However the image content still does not update, I'm always seeing the first image that was shown :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you only see the first image is very likely related to caching of the browser. To overcome this issue a simple solution is to add a varying query string to the image src as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/126831/2870069).
Thus your `show_figs` method could look like:

```py
import time
def show_figs(directory="figures", file_name="fig1.png"):
    s = """<figure>\n\t<img src="{0}?{1}" alt="The figure" width="304" height="228">\n</figure>""".format(os.path.join(directory, file_name),time.time())
    display(HTML(s))
```

In combination with the `clear_output` function you should be able to get your updated image.